# Deleting mysql database row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my MySQL database, in table `wp_usermeta`, I have a row named `custom_badges`. I want to remove all instances of this row within this table.

Using phpmyadmin, what SQL query can I run to delete this row completely?

EDIT: For clarification, here is a screenshot of the structure of the table:

[image]

So I want to delete all `meta_key` instances of `custom_badges`...

Comment: Is it a row or a column? And what means "I want to remove all instances of this row within this table."

Comment: please give the table structure of wp_usermeta and an example instance of these custom_badges instances

Comment: @Jens As far as I understand, it is a row. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/LescCNZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to miss some details, as a row cannot have a name. I guess what you mean is that the first column in the row has the value 'custom_badges'. In that case, just check what the name of that column is (let's say 'my_column' for example) and then run:

delete from wp_usermeta where my_column = 'custom_badges'

to delete the rows.

EDIT: Given the extra information from Henrik, the correct SQL is:

delete from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'custom_badges'

Comment: Sorry, I am learning the terminology. See this screenshot for an explanation: http://i.imgur.com/LescCNZ.png

Comment: That screenshot doesn't help much  :-)   At the top of the column containing 'custom_badges' you should see the name of the column. You can then use that column name in the delete statement I gave above. You can also run 'select * from wp_usermeta where my_column = 'custom_badges'' first, just to check that you're selecting the right rows, before running the delete.

Comment: I think my confusion is that I am misunderstand what we call "column" and what we call "row". What information can I give you to confirm the structure of my table?

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, click on Structure for the wp_usermeta table, and post a screenshot. The click on Browse, ideally showing the full screen from which you took the single-row screenshot, and post that.

Comment: Got it, please see the following screenshot, this should clear it up: http://i.imgur.com/hjwWFjc.jpg

Comment: So then the SQL you need to use is:  delete from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'custom_badges'

Comment: Works great! Thank you, please update your answer with this solution and I will accept it as correct.